# Upload image to azure storage using Qt/c++

Tags: c++, qt, rest, azure, qnetworkrequest

*Can anyone help me to upload image to azure storage using qt/c++*

## here's my code. it seems to have an error on constructing the headers.*

```
    QByteArray data;
    QFile file("Bg.jpg");
      if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
       {
            data.append(file.readAll());   //let's read the file
       }
    QString date = QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("ddd, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss") + " GMT";
    QString header = QString("PUT\n\n\n%1\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob\nx-ms-date:%2\nx-ms-version:2013-08-15\n/mycontainer/todate/").arg(data.length()).arg(date);

    QString urlUri = "http://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/todate";
    QByteArray ba = header.toUtf8();

    unsigned char* signature = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(ba.data());
    QByteArray kba = 

    QByteArray::fromBase64("key");
    unsigned char* key = (unsigned char*) kba.data();
    unsigned char result[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
    unsigned int result_len;
    ENGINE_load_builtin_engines();
    ENGINE_register_all_complete();

    HMAC_CTX ctx;
    HMAC_CTX_init(&ctx);
    HMAC_Init_ex(&ctx, key, strlen((const char*)key), EVP_sha256(), NULL);
    HMAC_Update(&ctx, signature, strlen((const char*)signature));
    HMAC_Final(&ctx, result, &result_len);
    HMAC_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);

    QByteArray array = QByteArray::fromRawData((char*)result, result_len);
    array = array.toBase64();  

    String version = "2013-08-15";

    QNetworkAccessManager* manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl(QUrl(urlUri));

    request.setRawHeader("Content-  Length",QString::number(data.length()).toStdString().c_str());
    request.setRawHeader("Content-Type","application/octet-stream");
    request.setRawHeader("x-ms-blob-type","BlockBlob");
    request.setRawHeader("x-ms-date", date.toStdString().c_str());
    request.setRawHeader("x-ms-version", version.toStdString().c_str());
    request.setRawHeader("Authorization","SharedKey myaccount:"+array);


    manager->post(request,data);
    connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this,SLOT(manageCloudReply(QNetworkReply*)));
```

**and this is the response on the request**

ï»¿`AuthenticationFailed` Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:82eb03cb-adf1-4797-bbc0-86c3e5ca3ec6
Time:2014-03-19T03:52:35.4790761ZThe MAC signature found in the HTTP request '3Dk7laN3XW+ASbQj0XddfmSnnuYfVSkhg/oRfSJekKY=' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'POST

87163

application/octet-stream

x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob
x-ms-date:Wed, 19 Mar 2014 11:52:05 GMT
x-ms-version:2013-08-15
/logboxstorage/mycontainer/todate'.

any help will be appreciated..thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the following line of code:

```
QString header = QString("PUT\n\n\n%1\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob\nx-ms-date:%2\nx-ms-version:2013-08-15\n/mycontainer/todate/").arg(data.length()).arg(date);
```

I see an extra slash (`/`) in `mycontainer/todate/`. Can you try by removing that?

Also look at the following code:

```
QString date = QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("ddd, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss") + " GMT";
```

[`currentDateTime()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdatetime.html#currentDateTime) will return the local date/time based on your computer. It should be `UTC/GMT` date/time. Try using [`currentDateTimeUtc()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdatetime.html#currentDateTimeUtc).

Another thing I noticed is that your request is going as `POST` to the server. It should be a `PUT` request.

Comment: thanks for the help. but the result is still the same

Comment: the datetime is valid as long as it is the current date with this format i think (Wed, 19 Mar 2014 13:58:20 GMT) because i've successfully get the list of container from my other code. the problem is that I dont know how will upload the image with the request.. thanks for the help.

Comment: That's not correct. Though the format is correct, the date/time represented should be in UTC. Otherwise you'll get `Request too old` error. Also check for request method. It should be a PUT request.

Comment: yes i know about the time and i've already encountered that. also i've changed the request to PUT and the result is still the same. thank you.